# I can't add the method by using addEventListner in Angular Project

Tags: angular

```
getCheckStatus(checkStatus: string) {
    let statusClass = '';
    if (checkStatus === 'Completed') {
      statusClass = 'mat-focus-indicator btn--primary__button mat-raised-button mat-button-base';
    } else {
      statusClass = 'mat-focus-indicator mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-button-disabled';
    }
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.className = statusClass;
    button.textContent = 'Close';
    button.addEventListener("click", () => this.popUp());
    const container = document.createElement('div');
    container.appendChild(button);    
    return container.innerHTML;
  }
```

```
popUp() {console.log('Finally this is working');}
```

I'm trying to call this method by adding addEventListner in my Angular Project. But this is not working, this popUp() method is never called.

MyAssumption: this is a JavaScript code, but we have to write in typescript in Angular, but I can't find any different syntax especially for typescript.

Comment: your assumption is not correct, infact you does not need `addEventListener` in angular. Also you dont need to create `button` like this in angular. use `ng-template`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
button.addEventListener("click", this.popUp.bind(this));
```

Comment: Why? How does it differ from `button.addEventListener("click", () => this.popUp());`?

Comment: You should code with this syntax in Angular, I think it works but I'm not sure.

Comment: `() => this.popUp()` and `this.popUp.bind(this)` are basically identical. Both create a function that call `this.popUp` (with proper `this`) value.